# python3: row length for json.dump(s)?

Tags: json, python-3.x, formatting

(Note: the above is *_not_* an answer. In this question, I am looking for a way to produce output that is syntactically correct JSON. That other discussion is about pretty-printing only and doesn't offer any solution about producing correct JSON. I originally made that stipulation here, but someone deleted it. I have reinstated that stipulation at the bottom of this message.)

In python3, I know I can do the following to get a readable dump of data:

```
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

However, if the data contains rows of data, the output is only one item per row.

For example, assuming this data ...

```
data = [
    [ 1, '2', 3 ],
    [ 4, '5', 6 ]
]
```

... doing the above-mentioned `json.dumps` produces this:

```
[
  [
    1,
    "2",
    3
  ],
  [
    4,
    "5",
    6
  ]
]
```

I prefer to have it dumped out like this:

```
[
  [
    1, "2", 3
  ],
  [
    4, "5", 6
  ]
]
```

Ideally, I'd like to provide a maximum row size, so that if I specify, say, row size = 2, the output would look like this:

```
[
  [
    1, "2",
    3
  ],
  [
    4, "5",
    6
  ]
]
```

I don't see any way within the `json` module to produce output like this.
Am I missing something?

Addendum:

I'm restating my deleted stipulation that the output should be syntactically correct JSON. I don't want something that is simply pretty-printed.

I now understand that there are no facilities in python to do this, and that it will have to be done either manually or via some sort of external package whose discussion is beyond the scope of this query.

Comment: No, and please don't ask for external projects, that's explicitly off topic.

Comment: JSON is an interchange format, not a pretty-printing format, so the Python `json` module has very little in the way of formatting the output. The `indent` argument is but a small concession to aid debugging.

Comment: I've duped this to a question on pretty-printing JSON, as it is reasonably comprehensive. The `json` module can't do what you are asking for.

Comment: OK. The extra package(s) I queried about were not meant to only be "external". But from your comment, I infer that there are no _internal_ python modules to do this, either.

Comment: No, the standard library only has `json`. You could write your own JSON encoder from scratch, I suppose, but there is nothing more high-level that does what you want.

Comment: Unless I missed something, that other discussion does not offer a python-based solution which produces syntactically correct JSON. You removed my stipulation about that in my original question, and I put it back. My question is not about pretty-printing, per se, because I want the results to always be readable under json.load(s).  Anyway, I realize now that this has to be done either manually or via some external tool.

Comment: @HippoMan ever found a solution? I'd be glad to know it if you have one. You may also want to consider adding it as an answer to your own question.